# Creating a dict of a dict from multiple lists on the fly

Tags: database, list, dictionary, python-2.7

I am pretty new to python and I am  trying to make a database using dicts in python 2.7.  I am now stumped on how to put the lists into a dict and then again into a dict for the database. I have been searching for weeks on how to do this . I have functions that get the album, artist, year, track number and path for MP3 files. I am getting the data I want I just don't know how to get the data in a dict of a dict. This loop below gives me the values of the keys I want to use.

```
    for x in FileList():
pathlist.append(x)
for artist in getArtist(x):
    artistlist.append(artist)
    for track in getTrack(x): 
        tracklist.append(track)
        for year in getYear(x):
            yearlist.append(year)
```

I hope I provided enough information for someone to help me figure this out. I am wanting to stay away from CSV files for the time being since I think it is important for me to know how to do this within Python.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: do not mix TAB and space characters, like you do in your example code.

For creating a dictionary with the various lists, just create the dictionary with appropriate keys and the list as values:

```
dict_of_list = dict(
    pathlist = pathlist,
    artistlist = artistlist,
    tracklist = tracklist,
    yearlist = yearlist,
)
```

or

```
dict_of_list = {
    'pathlist': pathlist,
    'artistlist': artistlist,
    'tracklist': tracklist,
    'yearlist': yearlist,
}
```

The second version of creating would allow keys other than strings.